# Swift UIViewController add UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I'm very new to swift! Is it possible to add a UISearchController and UITableView to a UIViewController class? But only display the UITableView when there's search data to display to the user.

I would like to implement something similar to the images below. DISREGARD the interface design colors and data.

[1. First View to display to user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XmwC.jpg)

[2. When user searches and data is returned display data in tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TC1jC.jpg)

**Update**

I solved my problem.. I used the below links to give me an idea on how to do what I was looking for.

1. [thorntech.com/2016/01/how-to-search-for-location-using-apples-mapkit/](http://thorntech.com/2016/01/how-to-search-for-location-using-apples-mapkit/)
2. [sweettutos.com/2015/09/30/how-to-use-the-google-places-autocomplete-api-with-google-maps-sdk-on-ios/](http://sweettutos.com/2015/09/30/how-to-use-the-google-places-autocomplete-api-with-google-maps-sdk-on-ios/)

Comment: Yes, its possible.

Comment: Could you give me some insight on how to do it. All the tutorials and stackoverflows I've seen are using tableviewcontroller instead of uiviewcontroller.

Comment: you can use a table view in uiviewcontroller, set it hidden to true, turn it false while searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will first need to create a UISearchController instance in the ViewController class and then integrate it with a searchBar delegate method for "textDidChange". For the tableView you can create a separate file and use it to integrate with the UISearchController. It sounds complicated but it can be easily done.
Check the below link for reference. Although it is not exactly won't you are looking for but it can give you an idea. Let me know if I am clear in my answer. Happy to help.

http://sweettutos.com/2015/09/30/how-to-use-the-google-places-autocomplete-api-with-google-maps-sdk-on-ios/

Comment: @awashington251, Great. If this has managed to resolve the issue then please uproot it.